# p4python create and submit a new file

Tags: perforce, p4python

How to create and submit a new file using p4python?

```
create_and_submit_file(full_path_in_depot, new_file_text_content):
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format=LOG_FORMAT)
    p4 = get_p4() # implemented
    try:  # Catch exceptions with try/except
        connect_and_login_p4(p4) # implemented

        # .. implementation here .. p4.some_call() 

        LOGGER.info('done')
    except P4Exception:
        for e in p4.errors:  # Display errors
            LOGGER.error(e)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file already exists on the local filesystem within a workspace, all you need to do is `p4.run_add(file)` and `p4.run_submit('-d', 'this is my awesome file')`.

If the file doesn't exist, you need to create it, and if you don't have a workspace, you need to create that too.  For the sake of brevity, here's how you'd do that from the command line completely from scratch (this maps pretty directly to P4Python but I don't know enough about your environment to give you code that'll work out of the box so I won't attempt the translation):

```
echo "my awesome file content" > my_awesome_file
p4 set P4CLIENT=my_awesome_client
p4 --field "View=//depot/... //my_awesome_client/..." client -o | p4 client -i
p4 add my_awesome_file
p4 submit -d "this is my awesome file"
```

Check out the example for `p4.save_client` to see a simple example of how you can create/modify a client spec with P4Python and modify the fields to suit your environment (similar to how I used the `--field` flag to set the `View` such that the root of `my_awesome_client` corresponds to `//depot/...`):

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/p4script/python.p4.html#python.p4.save_spectype

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Now i have difficulties with [Warning]: 'C:\\FilePath\\file.txt - file(s) not on client.' Client view is not always updated locally. Do you know where helix core stores cthe lient spec?

Comment: It's stored on the server.  You need to call `p4 client` (or `p4 client -i` or `p4.save_client`) to update the client spec; there is no such thing as a "local" copy of the client view.

Comment: Note that in typical usage you don't create/update a client spec every time you add a file!  You usually just have one client spec per workspace, define it one time, and then use that client spec for every operation within that workspace.  Since I don't know the wider context of what your tool is doing I'm not sure to what extent that makes sense.

Comment: I'm writing a server to create text files in helix core. Wanted to create a client for every user request with a view for exactly requested file folder - to avoid sync the whole depot. Can not solve how to create a stream client with different mappings in view (only needed folders).  But after I changed view to map the whole stream to the client root - it started to work properly.